# Yandex карта на сайт. Выдает ошибку при подставлении координат

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

На странице есть кнопки по клику на которые выскакивает попап окно. Каждой кнопке должно соответствовать свое содержание попап окна (карта и отметка ней). Все окна выскакивают - с этим гуд.

Проблема в том, что окно пустое. DevTools ругается.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Помогите)))

```
<div class="map" id="mapBranches"></div>
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.map-button');

    let coordinates = [
        [59.907185064216456, 30.32360249999998],
        [56.82273506788084, 60.611883499999976],
        [47.24534707428573, 39.7049965],
        [53.223802571189786, 50.19369900000003],
        [55.04674406964771, 82.95779049999999],
        [54.78367356988649, 56.040994499999876],
        [45.02704307457372, 39.02962499999993],
        [51.685813572274064, 39.17126249999992],
        [43.14411057453034, 131.90757449999995],
        [55.75232856899768, 49.16086099999994],
    ];
    let center;

    buttons.forEach((button, index) => {
        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            center = coordinates[index];
        });
    });

    function init() {
        let map = new ymaps.Map('mapBranches', {
            center: center,
            zoom: 16,
        });

        let placemarkBranches = new ymaps.Placemark(center, {}, {});

        map.geoObjects.add(placemarkBranches);
    };

    ymaps.ready(init);

});
```

Comment: Вы инициализируете карту, подавая ей переменную `center`, которая на момент инициализации карты не имеет значения, поэтому и ругается DevTools. Задайте переменной `center` значение по умолчанию, для начала. Вдобавок ко всему, если вы будете менять переменную `center`, центр карты и координаты метки не поменяются, поэтому вам нужно менять непосредственно опции карты и метки на ней.

Comment: А какое значение по умолчанию в моем случае будет корректным?

Comment: Это вам виднее. Ваш же код. Если вы говорите, что это попап, то можете любые координаты использовать.

Comment: значение по умолчанию для center логично задать в виде пустого массива же. `let center = []`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь